# Performance based Job Scheduling in NodeJS for child_process.execFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, saas

I'm currently developing a backend for a Webservice powered by NodeJS. The Webservice used to Execute some Algorithms (Specifically Video Processing Algorithms which take some time to execute) Which compiled as binary executables (This is because of proprietary algorithms). There is no parallelism in binaries.

When some request come to specific route, the backend will execute the corresponding algorithm executable and report the result back the user, for example, checkout following code:

```js
// app is an instance of expressjs
// push request in order to trigger algorithm_1 executable
app.post("/api/algorithm_1_executable", (req,res,next)=>{

  // execute algorithm_1 binary
  const child_algorithm_1 = execFile('./executables/algorithms_1'), 
  ["some arguments", "for algorithm_1 execuatable"], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  // Do something with the result
})
```

As I mentioned before the algorithms can take a while to finish due to some heavy processing stuff related to the video files. I know that `child_process.exeFile()` will spawn a new process and run the executable.

My question is how I can schedule this executions, my observations show that if 4 of these binaries running at the same time the CPU utilization moved to about 90% (In test server) and thus if another request comes it certainly throttle other processes. in this case I want to begin processing new request when some of the already running processes finished.

How can I achieve this goal? Is this right way to this kind of WebServices?

Notes:

- The Development Test Server is Running, Windows Server 2016.
- I'm currently developing using NodeJS 12.13 LTS (In case of some recommendations of other approaches for achieving this, for example, using newly added "Worker Threads". )
- As I mentioned before since the algorithms shipped in binary files I can't use some NodeJS tools like C++ N-API ( ABI (Application Binary Interface))

Comment: You should consider pushing the long-running task into a job queue. The job queue can be configured to process N jobs at once, preventing CPU over-utilization. When the queue worker finishes a job, an event can be fired back to the client, letting the user and your UI know the processing has completed. [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) is one Node.js job queue option.

Comment: Actually I have email-based notification system( using nodemailer) to notify user I heard that push notification not very performance efficient. for first part of the answer how can I monitor cpu utilization in realtime ?

Comment: Again, there are many ways of doing this. One would be to add something like [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html) to your server to monitor and limit the workers based on CPU usage, memory consumption, etc..

Comment: monit is unix based monitoring tool, as I mentioned in the notes my test server is running Windows Server 2016